# man pages for Javascript for use within VIM

Tags: javascript, vim, manpage

I couldn't find a good answer for this question so I figured I'd ask.  I'd really like to find some man pages for javascript for use within VIM.  This way I could place my cursor over a method or global object and press K in command mode to open up information related to this javascript item.  Obviously there is no official javascript manual as it varies from browser to browser, but I was hoping there might be something like this.  I'm working exclusively with google chrome which I have heard essentially implements ECMAScript 5, so the manuals that are closest to this would be preferable.  As a side note, I've seen that there are some chm's but I'm not aware if I can use the 'man' command to navigate these.  Is what I'm asking for possible (and in existence), and if so where can I find it?  Thanks!

Comment: Linux, specific Ubuntu Oneric Ocelot

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists. The closest would be a function that opens a web browser at the MDN page corresponding to the current word. Hmmm… it doesn't look like a hard task… Not something I can do ATM, though.

Comment: Related: [MDN javascript docs for offline use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501882/mdn-javascript-docs-for-offline-use#comment12642976_9501882)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess [doctorjs](https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs) is what you're searching for, and you need [ctag](https://github.com/vim-scripts/ctags.vim) & [taglist](https://github.com/vim-scripts/taglist.vim) first.

Comment: And then I find a guide [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777366/recommended-vim-plugins-for-javascript-coding/5893600#5893600)