# How can one download Mozilla's developer's documentation for offline reading?

Tags: javascript, html, mozilla, application-cache, offline-browsing

Until recently, one could conveniently download Mozilla's developer's documentation, `developer.mozilla.org.tar.gz`, for offline reading.  However, Mozilla seems to have upgraded the documentation to a new, SQL-based format, abandoning the old TAR.GZ.

One does not doubt that such an upgrade is good, but I do not understand the upgrade, so now I am confused.  How should I now read Mozilla's developer's documentation offline?

**REFERENCES**

- [An earlier, now seemingly obsolete question and answer on the topic on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18490433/1275653)
- [Mozilla's explanation, which regrettably I do not understand.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/About#Download_content)

Comment: I'm interested in the correct answer, but my guess is that they intend it to be viewed using one of the two programs under the "Third Party Tools" heading, from your second link. Can anyone verify?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MDN javascript docs for offline use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501882/mdn-javascript-docs-for-offline-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below seems dead, here's how to do as of https://kapeli.com/mdn_offline (mentioned by deleted answer below):

> #### Offline MDN Docs
>
> You can download the MDN docs using the table below. Before
> downloading, please consider using a documentation
> browsing app like [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash) (macOS), [Velocity](http://velocity.silverlakesoftware.com/) (Windows) or
> [Zeal](http://zealdocs.org/) (Linux) instead. These apps will help you get the most out
> of the docs, by providing a search index and quick access to
> everything you need.
>
> [CSS.tgz](https://frankfurt.kapeli.com/feeds/zzz/mdn/CSS.tgz)  1 December 2020  [HTML.tgz](https://frankfurt.kapeli.com/feeds/zzz/mdn/HTML.tgz)  1 December 2020
> [JavaScript.tgz](https://frankfurt.kapeli.com/feeds/zzz/mdn/JavaScript.tgz)   1 December 2020 Note: Includes DOM docs
> [SVG.tgz](https://frankfurt.kapeli.com/feeds/zzz/mdn/SVG.tgz)  1 December 2020

---

It is advertised.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/About#Downloading_content states

> #### Downloading content
>
> You can download [a full tarball mirror of MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/media/developer.mozilla.org.tar.gz).

Comment: Both download links are dead. I tried to download the page with wget -m -K -E -k -p -r -np -v  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web but downloaded links seem to be broken, and it does not finish within 3 days, therefore I stopped.

Comment: @NikolaiEhrhardt : seems to work with  Pauls' answer

Answer (score 4):

At this writing, one can still download from the apparently unadvertised URL  https://developer.mozilla.org/media/developer.mozilla.org.tar.gz.  Whether Mozilla will retain this unadvertised option, or eventually retire it, I do not know.

Comment: Not working anymore. October 2023.

Answer (score 2):

MDN content available on github https://github.com/mdn/content

1. clone github repository `git clone https://github.com/mdn/content`
2. `cd content`
3. install yarn if not installed `npm install -g yarn` on linux `sudo npm install -g yarn`
4. execute `yarn install`
5. execute `yarn start`
6. navigate to http://localhost:5000 using your favorite web browser

for more details read https://github.com/mdn/content/blob/main/README.md

Comment: I get this error: 00h00m00s 0/0: : ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'start', yarn --version
0.32+git, Installed with apt-get install yarn on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471063/yarn-error-there-are-no-scenarios-must-have-at-least-one

Comment: I didn't notice this is a 6 year old question, I suppose this is relevant now since the introduction of [MDN Yari](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2020/12/welcome-yari-mdn-web-docs-has-a-new-platform/)

Comment: I install sudo apt-get install yarnpkg and tried yarnpkg start, but node module had to old version. I upgraded with this guide: https://www.itzgeek.com/post/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04/#2-install-nodejs-using-nvm, but I still got error on yarnpkg start: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator'

Comment: Try to execute yarn install to install required packages