# Yarn ERROR: There are no scenarios; must have at least one

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, debian, yarnpkg, debian-based

I tried to install [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/) and when I used the `yarn` command I got:

```
00h00m00s 0/0: : ERROR: There are no scenarios; must have at least one.
```

my `yarn --version` is `0.32`. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 342, accepted):

It looks like that I was trying to execute the wrong yarn, because simply running `sudo apt install yarn` on my Ubuntu 18.04 gave me [yarn from cmdtest](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/yarn.1.html).

So I solved by uninstalling it:

```
sudo apt remove yarn
```

And by installing it as the [official website explains](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/), which in my case (Ubuntu 18.04) it was the following:

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn

yarn
```

Comment: I found `sudo apt remove yarn` didn't do anything, I had to use `sudo apt remove cmdtest`

Comment: For me, in the last step, I tried this `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends yarn` and it worked. That was after doing `sudo apt update`

Comment: the command sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn also remove cmdtest

Answer (score 113):

You've got the wrong yarn. The yarn you're executing comes from the `cmdtest` package. Uninstalling cmdtest first should fix this:

`sudo apt remove cmdtest`

Once you've uninstalled it, run the commands below to install yarn properly:

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install yarn
```

Comment: I'm using Mint 20. I've tried other solutions, but only that one worked for me. Thanks!
But I still got some errors while loading these commands:
E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt ulyana-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu ulyana Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: This answer has the most relevant and easy-to-use code, for copying + pasting. Thx.

Comment: this answer is most relevant for debian-based linux users who were "guided" by the terminal to install cmdtest instead of yarn.

Comment: This answer has the correct set of commands. This worked for me .

Comment: You are an angel!

Comment: removing cmdtest is the key

Answer (score 28):

The real name you should use when installing is yarnpkg

```
sudo apt install yarnpkg
```

That is the solution.

Answer (score 16):

Try this step by step. This worked for me.

```
sudo apt remove yarn
sudo apt install curl
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install yarn
```

Answer (score 15):

```
sudo npm install -g yarn
```

then open a new terminal window and type `yarn --version`

Answer (score 9):

It looks like that you was trying to execute the wrong yarn, because simply running `sudo apt install yarn` on your *Ubuntu 18.04* gave you yarn from `cmdtest`.

To solve this problem  you should install yarn from its official website **https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install**. I recommend to read more about yarn on above website

1. To transfer data you can use from curl

   ```
   curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
   ```

   The output looks like this:

   ```
   OK
   ```
2. To know either data was transferred or not , you can display that text/string by using **echo** command( it is linux built-in command)

   ```
   echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
   ```

   The output also looks like following:

   ```
   deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main
   ```
3. To download package information from all configured sources run following:

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn
   ```
4. After this stage finished check yarn version by

   ```
   yarn --version
   ```

   The output looks like this

   ```
   1.22.18
   ```

#### Or you can install yarn by npm

```
npm install -g yarn
```

Answer (score 5):

I began to receive this error after upgrade to nodejs.
The steps to fix those bugs were :

1. `sudo apt remove cmdtest`
2. `sudo apt autoremove`
3. `sudo npm install -g yarn`

Answer (score 2):

Just an update

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/yarnpkg.gpg
sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn
yarn
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

it is name **"yarnpkg"** ,not "yarn"

```sh
#which yarn
/usr/bin/yarn

# which yarnpkg
/usr/bin/yarnpkg

#yarn --version
0.32+git

# yarnpkg --version
1.22.10


# cat /usr/bin/yarn

#!/usr/bin/python3
# Copyright 2013  Lars Wirzenius
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
# =*= License: GPL-3+ =*=


import cliapp
...




# cat /usr/bin/yarnpkg 


#!/usr/bin/env node

/* eslint-disable no-var */
/* eslint-disable flowtype/require-valid-file-annotation */
'use strict';

var ver = process.versions.node;
var majorVer = parseInt(ver.split('.')[0], 10);

if (majorVer < 4) {
  console.error('Node version ' + ver + ' is not supported, please use Node.js 4.0 or higher.');
  process.exit(1); // eslint-disable-line no-process-exit
} else {
  try {
    require(__dirname + '/../lib/v8-compile-cache.js');
  } catch (err) {
    // We don't have/need this on legacy builds and dev builds
  }

  // Just requiring this package will trigger a yarn run since the
  // `require.main === module` check inside `cli/index.js` will always
  // be truthy when built with webpack :(
  // `lib/cli` may be `lib/cli/index.js` or `lib/cli.js` depending on the build.
  var cli = require(__dirname + '/../lib/cli');
  if (!cli.autoRun) {
    cli.default().catch(function(error) {
      console.error(error.stack || error.message || error);
      process.exitCode = 1;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use `NPM` to install yarn.
To achieve this, do:

- `npm install --global yarn`
- `yarn --version`

[learn more](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#debian-stable)

Answer (score 0):

step 1 -> **sudo apt remove cmdtest**

step 2 -> Download yarnpkg key
**curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -**
**output - OK**

step 3 -> Download deb yarn list
**echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list**

step 4 -> Update and install yarn
**sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn**

step 5 -> Check yarn version
**yarn --version**
**output - 1.22.19**

Answer (score -2):

sudo apt install --no-install-recommends yarn

Comment: When posting an answer, please explain what was wrong and how the answer fixes the issue.